# How to change RactiveJs locale

Tags: ractivejs

Is it possible to change ractive instance locale?

I'm not quite sure what locale RactiveJs uses by default but floating point numbers are rendered as xxx.xx in my browser while the locale I want to specify uses a comma as a delimeter. So I want to change the locale that bindings use to format floating point values.

Comment: And your code is... where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not a string, Ractive will evaluate your data using `toString()` on it.

May I suggest you create a simple component that does the job you need?

```
Ractive.components.LocalNumber = Ractive.extend({

    computed: {
        formattedVal: function() {
            return (val || 0).toLocaleString();
        }
    },

    template: '{{ formattedVal }}'
});
```

Like so you can use this in any Ractive instance:

```
new Ractive({
    el: document.body,

    data: function() {
        return {
            numeric: 42.42
        }
    },

    template: '<LocalNumber val={{ numeric }} />'
})
```

See in action in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2v06khLn/